# How do I hide the first and last line break but leave the ones in between text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to hide `br` before and after text while leaving 2 in between text to fit the content in mobile view

For this example:

```
<p> 
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> 
Example text 
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> 
Example text 
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> 
Example text 
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> 
</p>
```

I'm looking to get hide the beginning and end `br` while leaving 2 in between text

Ex.

```
<p> 
<br /> display: none 
<br /> display: none 
<br /> display: none 
Example text 
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> display: none 
Example text 
<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> display: none 
Example text 
<br /> display: none 
<br /> display: none 
<br /> display: none 
</p>
```

NOTE: I don't want to remove the `br` I want to keep them but hide on mobile

At first I was only checking for first and last child being `br` with the code below

```
const isBr = (el) => {
  return el && el.nodeType === 1 && el.tagName === 'BR';
};

const isText = (node) => {
  return node.nodeType === 3 && /^\s*$/.test(node.data);
};

export const isFirstOrLastChildBr = (el) => {
  let first = el.firstChild;
  if (isText(first)) first = first.nextSibling;
  if (isBr(first)) return true;

  let last = el.lastChild;
  if (isText(last)) last = last.previousSibling;
  if (isBr(last)) return true;

  return false;
};
```

If it was true I would hide all `br` if not I would hide all but 2. However it doesn't work if the first/last child is `br` *and* there's text in between

Comment: Ideal solution is not use extra br tags, but CSS so you can format it for mobile.

Comment: Don't use line breaks for formatting. That's not their purpose, and it's a poor substitute for proper layout. Changing margin or padding with media queries is trivial.

Comment: @epascarello I have no control over how many `br` tags are added so not sure I how I would handle this in CSS

Comment: @isherwood the breaks are added by the text editor being used. I'm only editing the html output

Comment: Still, maybe show us more context so we can offer better solutions. This seems hacky and frustrating.

Comment: @niknaks Maybe hide all `<br>`s using CSS, and adjust spaces with CSS.

Comment: If you are unsure how much space a `<br />` tag takes up, you can always inspect the element in a browser. I checked and seems it take `18.5px` so, all you need to do in css is give 18.5 * the number of `<br />` tags you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can target the br elements and hide them.

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  p>br:nth-child(-n+3),
  p>br:nth-child(3n + 3),
  p>br:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> Example text
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> Example text
  <br />
  <br />
  <br /> Example text
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</p>
```